# Can Intellij be used with a Visual-Studio-Code style docker devcontainer?

Tags: node.js, docker, intellij-idea

I've been using devcontainers in Node development in VSC and enjoy the idea that I can commit a shared configuration to ensure everyone on the team has the same runtime/buildtime.  I've been looking for a similar way to configure IntelliJ, but am having some difficulties determining if this is even possible.

I am running IntelliJ 2020.2 and have the Node Remote Interpreter plugin installed.

In my devcontainer, I map a Docker volume `node_modules` to my workspace such that all my different containers can share the same volume, and not need to re-download the set of npm modules everytime.

I have setup & created an appropriate Run/Debug Docker configuration, and when I launch it, the container is built & configured properly.  However, in IntelliJ, understandably, the `node_modules` folder still remains blank (as that folder is only mounted in the remote container).

Similarly, I have setup a remote Node run configuration pointing to my docker image, but similarly, IntelliJ does not see any libraries that are supposed to be in the node_modules folder.

Is there any way to work with this kind of configuration in IntelliJ such that the IDE understands the mappings I create in my Docker container?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

no, there is no such feature in IDEA. Please vote for [IDEA-202267](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202267) to be notified on any progress with this feature request

Comment: That is a big disappointment.  I am disappointed to see that I cannot use IntelliJ to work on code without having complete local installations of all tooling required.

Comment: I noticed that there is also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226455 to vote and track

Answer (score 9):

**Update 28th October 2022**

JetBrains seems to integrate GitHub Codespaces as [a full supported JetBrains Gateway Provider](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20060-github-codespaces). So maybe there will be a direct support of the [open sourced Dev Container spec](https://github.com/devcontainers/spec/blob/main/docs/specs/devcontainer-reference.md) soon.

**Original answer**

JetBrains now [supports GitPod as a first class citizen implementation for the Development Containers concept](https://www.gitpod.io/blog/gitpod-jetbrains). Both IntelliJ Idea and the next-gen IDE Fleet are supported. Also JetBrains Space would be an option, if you have licences for it in your company. There's [a landing page that present all the options](https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/):

[image]

In contrast to the VSCode style implementation of the concept where you configure your Dev Containers using a `devcontainer.json` [with GitPod you use a `.gitpod.yml`](https://www.gitpod.io/docs/getting-started). But [GitPod is already working actively on supporting the `devcontainer.json` format](https://github.com/gitpod-io/gitpod/issues/7721), which was [Open Sourced by Microsoft here](https://github.com/devcontainers/spec/blob/main/docs/specs/devcontainer-reference.md).

More details and in-depth review of the Development Containers concept can be found [in this post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2022/06/dev-containers-github-codespaces/).

Comment: There are some uses for that, but running the development environment in the cloud is not acceptable to many either due to concerns about network performance or because they want to keep the source code within their private network.

Comment: GitPod is a little bit different, Docker Desktop now allow to run local containers and work inside using Visual Studio Code https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/ . But unfortunately JetBrains not support it.

Answer (score 7):

Jetbrains released [Dev Containers Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21962-dev-containers/versions) starting from June 2023

Comment: Installed it, cant seem to find it in SDK selection... how do I activate it for building/testing?